# How do I pass state between pages using react navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass state from main page to a details page. The details page changes the parent state successfully by calling function (via props). However, a re-render is not triggered and the details page is not updated (despite it having updated props correctly). How can I pass state to a child page (details) such that it will trigger it to re-render?

It seems like a similar question is asked [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1585)
 but I don't quite understand it. I'm not using redux as this is a small app.

```
//Navigator Setup
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home} 
    Details: {
        screen: Details}
);

//Home page:
this.props.navigation.navigate("Details", {
    changeDetails: this.changeDetails
    details: this.state.details})
}

//Details page
let details = props.navigation.getParam("details", "n/a");
let changeDetails = props.navigation.getParam("changeDetails", "n/a");

//change things
//render stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing the data with `navigation.navigate` won't trigger a re-render since it is passing a copy of the props. You will need to find an other way to send the props so that your component gets aware of the changes. 
You can for example connect your component to your redux state (assuming you're using redux). If you are not using redux, you can send a refresh fucntion from your parent component `navigate('Child', { refresh: refreshFunction }` to the Child

You can then access this function in the child ( via something like `this.props.navigation.state.params.refresh();`or `const refresh() = this.props.navigation.getParam('regresh')` ) before the back action. This will trigger updating the parent state to update.

I hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for the details about passing a copy!  I am not using redux. Can you share an example of a refresh function? forceUpdate() doesn't work, as I don't think it propagates.

Comment: Your refresh function can be simply be `refreshFunction = (name) => (value) => {this.setState([name]: value)}` . From the child Component you can simply use it to set `name`to the value you want on the parent Component.'`<TextInput
        onChangeText={this.refresh("name")}
        ...
      />`

Answer (score 0):

as document say:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('YOUR TARGET NAME', {
          itemId: 86,
          otherParam: 'anything you want here',
        });
```

[here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html) is the full example,good luck

**edit :**
in child component in `componentDidUpdate()` method you must check that if props are changed set new props to state,then component will be re-rendered with new state's:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
      if ('YOUR DATA FROM PARENT' != 'PREVIOUS DATA FROM PARENT SAVED IN STATE'){
                this.setState({yourState: 'YOUR DATA FROM PARENT'})
       }
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing.  See code under //home page

Answer (score 0):

You have pass the data in correct way but while extracting the data you went wrong 
`let details = props.navigation.getParam("details", "n/a");`
just put `this.props` 
like this
`console.log(props.navigation.getParam.changeDetails);
 console.log(props.navigation.getParam.details)`
console.log is just for debugging purpose you can assign it to any variable And you will receive the data in object form or in `json` form.set this in constructor, render() or where you want to use this data

Comment: I can successfully access my props has it is via console.  There are two formats to get params from react navigation, see: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html